# Web server don't send [SYN, ACK] to certain subnets

Tags: http, windows-server-2008, tcp

We have a Windows server 2008 that don't respond to http requests from certain subnets(xxx.xxx.120.0), while it works perfect from others(xxx.xxx.140.0)

The xxx.xxx.120.0 is NAT(PAT) I think.

Where shall I start?

From Wireshark at server:

```
118 104.030954000   xxx.xxx.120.14  server.company.com  TCP 66  59232 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1380 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
119 107.039990000   xxx.xxx.120.14  server.company.com  TCP 66  [TCP Retransmission] 59232 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1380 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
120 113.046040000   xxx.xxx.120.14  server.company.com  TCP 62  [TCP Retransmission] 59232 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1380 SACK_PERM=1
```

EDIT: Formatted wireshark output

EDIT2: I guess there should be a 3-way handshake, which I can see for the working subnets. Since I'm actually not a server or network guy, I don't know if it's OS or IIS who take care of the handshake.

EDIT3: xxx.xxx.140.0 can ping server, xxx.xxx.120.0 cannot...

Comment: Are the working and error subnets the same (xxx.xxx.120.0)? Is the HTTP request handled by IIS? I formatted the output from wireshark...

Comment: Working subnet is xxx.xxx.140.0. Thanks for formatting help ...  =)

Comment: It would be on the NIC/OS level the SYN request. (I've added the IIS part because I couldn't see the output from wireshark) - sorry... Can you ping the server?

Comment: xxx.xxx.140.0 can ping server, xxx.xxx.120.0 cannot...

Comment: OK - Start looking at the NAT rules. NAT will transfer all messages on a specific port (for HTTP it will be port 80) from the xxx.xxx.120.0 subnet to the receiving network/server.

Comment: But NAT is working since the client request gets through to web server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only writing this as an answer as continuing in the comments field isn't appropriate...

From the wireshark response it seems that it sends a SYN request, but you never receive a ACK from the server. This means that the request is not getting to the server. This is not HTTP specific but network related.

The first step would be to make a traceroute (tracert <server ip> in windows command prompt). Find the last hub of that response and see if it isn't a router...

Next step would be to consult a network guy.

Comment: But Wireshark capture is from the server, so 1st SYN gets there.